# Find duplicates and color the entire row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very large table and I need to be able to form a better and faster overview.

In my column F I have addresses listed. I want to find all the addresses that are the same, and mark the whole row with a color, if the value in column D is also the same.

If it says "Address 1" in two rows in column F, then it must check the value in column D. If the value in column D is ex. 1 in both rows, then the rows must be colored, but are the values in column D different ex. 1 and 2, then the rows should not be colored.

Comment: Use conditional formatting.

Comment: Is it possible when it depends on two different cells?

Comment: yes you can add a formula in the condition

Comment: @Anne Definitely possible. Use custom formula. Provide some sample data.